# Morris inorder traversal

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

Morris Inorder traversal - an algorithm for in-order traversal, of a tree, without recursion of extra memory. Looking for code review, optimizations and best practices.

```
public class MorrisInOrder<T> {

    TreeNode<T> root;

    /**
     * Takes in a BFS representation of a tree, and converts it into a tree.
     * here the left and right children of nodes are the (2*i + 1) and (2*i + 2)nd
     * positions respectively.
     * 
     * @param items The items to be node values.
     */
    public MorrisInOrder(List<? extends T> items) {
        create(items);
    }

    private void create (List<? extends T> items) {
        root = new TreeNode<T>(null, items.get(0), null);

        final Queue<TreeNode<T>> queue = new LinkedList<TreeNode<T>>();
        queue.add(root);

        final int half = items.size() / 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < half; i++) {
            if (items.get(i) != null) {
                final TreeNode<T> current = queue.poll();                
                final int left = 2 * i + 1;
                final int right = 2 * i + 2;

                if (items.get(left) != null) {
                    current.left = new TreeNode<T>(null, items.get(left), null);
                    queue.add(current.left);
                }
                if (right < items.size() && items.get(right) != null) {
                    current.right = new TreeNode<T>(null, items.get(right), null);
                    queue.add(current.right);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static class TreeNode<T> {
        TreeNode<T> left;
        T item;
        TreeNode<T> right;

        TreeNode(TreeNode<T> left, T item, TreeNode<T> right) {
            this.left = left;
            this.item = item;
            this.right = right;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the inorder traversal of the tree.
     * 
     * @return list containing inorder traversal of elements
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException 
     */
    public List<T> inOrder() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        if (root == null) throw new NoSuchAlgorithmException("The root is null.");

        final List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        TreeNode<T> current  = root;

        while (current != null) {
            if (current.left == null) {
                list.add(current.item);
                current = current.right;
            } else {
                TreeNode<T> predecessor = current.left;
                /*
                 * found the in-order predecessor.
                 */
                while (predecessor.right != null && predecessor.right != current) {
                    predecessor = predecessor.right;
                }

                if (predecessor.right == null) {
                    // hook it up.
                    predecessor.right = current;
                    current = current.left;
                } else {
                    list.add(current.item);
                    predecessor.right = null;
                    current  = current.right;
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}


public class MorrisInOrderTest {

    @Test
    public void testBalancedTree() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        final MorrisInOrder<Integer> morrisInOrder1 = new MorrisInOrder<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7));
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(4, 2, 5, 1, 6, 3, 7), morrisInOrder1.inOrder());
    }


    @Test
    public void testUnBalancedTree() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        final MorrisInOrder<Integer> morrisInOrder2 = new MorrisInOrder<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, null, null));
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(4, 2, 5, 1, 3), morrisInOrder2.inOrder());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
private void create (List<? extends T> items) {
    root = new TreeNode<T>(null, items.get(0), null);
```

This crashes if an empty list is passed in. And since you have this function...

```
public MorrisInOrder(List<? extends T> items) {
    create(items);
}
```

It's entirely possible for such a thing to happen.

---

```
final int left = 2 * i + 1;
final int right = 2 * i + 2;
```

`right` can be set to `left + 1` instead.

---

```
current  = current.right;
```

and

```
TreeNode<T> current  = root;
```

There's an extra space in here.

---

```
            /*
             * found the in-order predecessor.
             */
            while (predecessor.right != null && predecessor.right != current) {
                predecessor = predecessor.right;
            }
```

You're using a block-style comment for single line comment. Why?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Pimgd's remarks I want to throw in:

#### Program against high Interfaces, not low ones:

Currently your methods all take a `List<? extends T>`. That in itself is quite nice already. Now a traversal of existing elements does not necessarily have to be done on an ordered Collection only.

I suggest you explore the possiblities of passing int `Collection<? extends T>` or even higher: `Iterable<? extends T>`